# Extjs Group Tab Panel switch widgets

Tags: view, widget, extjs4.1, tabpanel

I have a Group Tab Panel which has three tabs(A,B,C). In my first tab (A) I have a button and when user clicks on button my Tab A View(Widget.x) should change to another View(Widget.Y).

I have used Update method, it didnt worked. I think update method is to update content. Also I tried to change alias of Tab A, it didn't work.

Can Someone help with this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like this question has nothing to do with tab panels and everything to do with simply adding/removing components from another component? If so, I'd consider revising your question since it's misleading.

Comment: I am pretty new to Extjs. I think we should get current active tab and change its item to point to new view rather than existing one.

Comment: Is the active tab the component itself, or is it a wrapping component which contains the item?

Comment: I had created a viewport and one of its item is grouptabpanel.
it contains three tab each tab points to view(xtype:"A"). I am using xtype to refer one of my views. I want to change the xtype dynamically and tab should load the changed view

Comment: So the component *is* the tab. In that case, just remove the tab and replace it with the component you want.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks a lot. I want my new tab to be displayed till a event is under progress in backend. IF the event is done I should change back my tab to original one. Also when user refresh the page, based on event tab should be loaded when I create tab using xtype how can i use if else condition to assign xtype to correct value.